# vector partition

Tags: co.combinatorics, partitions

I am interested in partitioning a vector with nonnegative integer entries into a sum of vectors with nonnegative integral entries. For example the partitions like (2,2) = (1,1)+(1,1) = (2,0)+(0,2) = (1,0)+(0,1)+(1,1) = ... .

I have the following questions:

1. Given a vector $\textbf{b} \ne \textbf{0}$ whether the number of such partitions is known in the literature?
2. What is the combinatorial significance of this number?

Kindly share your views on these questions and thanks for your valuable time.

Have a good day.

Comment: I'm presuming you want your vectors to be nonzero. Here's the 1-dimensional case: https://oeis.org/A000041

Comment: @Billy I have edited the nonzero condition part.

Comment: For some references, see https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0202253.pdf and its bibliography.

Comment: @RichardStanley Dear sir,  Thanks for the nice reference.

Comment: Vector partitions are also called multipartite partitions. You might search for information under that name.

Answer (score 4):

For rather trivial reasons, 
 $$
1+\sum_{(k,l)\ne (0,0)}p(k,l)x^ky^l=\prod_{(p,q)\ne(0,0)}\frac{1}{1-x^py^q} .
 $$
Since these numbers include, as $p(n,0)$, the one-dimensional partition numbers, you cannot really find a "closed" formula.

Similarly to how pentagonal numbers in the usual partition formulas arise in the context of Lie algebra cohomology, the denominator of this formula makes one think of the cohomology of the Lie algebra of Hamiltonian vector fields on the 2D plane, see [this article](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10688-014-0053-0) and references therein.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to look into the Kostant partition function, and the generalization, the vector partition function. There is a lot of literature about this ,see e.g. [these slides.](http://math.sfsu.edu/beck/papers/vectorpar.slides.pdf)